# Objective-C set accessor

Tags: objective-c

When I declare a property in objective-C, I also add the synthesize clause to get accessors

```
 @interface StoreManager ()
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *writeStoresTimer;

 @implementation StoreManager
 @synthesize writeStoresTimer
```

I usually use the following syntax to set value to a property

```
 [self setWriteStoresManager:@"Data"];
```

Is the above statement same as self.writeStoresTimer = @"Data" ? Will this also call the set-accessor

Comment: Question answered. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes self. and set uses accessors
only time you dont is when your within the same class and just use the pointers name

Answer (score 2):

> Is the above statement same as self.writeStoresTimer = @"Data"?

Yes, it is exactly the same.

Indeed, if you want to override the default setter method that is automatically synthesized, you define:

```
- (void)setWriteStoresTimer:(NSString *)string;
```

and then your custom implementation will be called through the dot-syntax.

From [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

> You can think of a property declaration as being equivalent to declaring two accessor methods. Thus
>
> ```
>    @property float value;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>    - (float)value;
>    - (void)setValue:(float)newValue;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They both do the same thing.

From Apple's Documentation:

> Objective-C provides a dot (.) operator that offers an alternative to
>   square bracket notation ([]) to invoke accessor methods. Dot syntax
>   uses the same pattern that accessing C structure elements uses:

You can see the full documentation in [The Objective C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17)